# Title cannot contain "Automatic import from npm to vue app"

Tags: vue.js, npm

npm is great to download some js libraries, but including the into a vue app is really hard. i have no idea if there is an "official" way, but searching online i see so many different approaches.

sometimes it is imported in the app.js file, sometimes in the .vue files inside the  tags. i have also seen that there are vue plugins that handle differently. how should i know if i have a vue plugin or not? i don't even know what the other option would be. like a vue module instead of a vue plugin?

is there a way that the vue app just includes/imports the stuff from node_modules so i can use it? so that after doing some npm install it is all available?

Answer (score 0):

Npm just downloads the library into the `node_modules` folder and let's you access it where you need it.
If it's a vue component you need to import it in a vue file, because that's where you need it.
If it's a vue plugin you have to import it in the main js file because that's where it gets initalized in the whole app.

Looks like you are new to vue, I suggest you to take a look at [this simple guide](https://medium.com/js-dojo/getting-started-with-vuejs-for-web-and-native-285dc64f0f0d) where you can learn some basic stuff.